# Problema con login en Java con conexion a base de datos(MySQL & Eclipse)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, login

Seguí un tutorial para crear un login conectado a MySQL, a la hora de correrlo 
e ingresar usuario y password me lanza el mensaje de error y en la consola muestra lo siguiente cada vez que ingresas el usuario y password de nuevo: 
                   **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM usuario' at line 1** .                                               Al parecer el problema no es con MySQL pues al usar el comando **SELECT * FROM  usuario** . Lo marca como row accepted. Les comparto el codigo por si alguien encuentra algo que me ayude:

```js
/**BASE DE DATOS EN MY SQL**/
CREATE DATABASE bd_login;
USE bd_login;
CREATE TABLE usuario (
idusuario int (11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
login varchar (50),
password varchar (38) 
);
INSERT INTO usuario (login,password) VALUES('Emmanuel','prueba1')
```

```js
package DB;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;


import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root root@127.0.0.1:3306
public class ConexionLogin {
 static String bd = "bd_login";
 static String login ="root";
 static String password ="1234";
 static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + bd;
 Connection conn = null;
 public ConexionLogin (){
  try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
  }
 catch(SQLException e){
  System.out.println(e);
  
 }
  catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
   System.out.println(e);
   
  }
 }
 public Connection getConnection(){
return conn;  
 }
 public void desconectar(){
  conn = null;
 }
}
```

```js
package DB;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Usuario {
 ConexionLogin cn;
 public Usuario(){
  cn = new ConexionLogin ();
 }
 public Object [][] UsuarioAcceder (String login, String password){
  int registros = 0;
  try {
   PreparedStatement pstm = cn.getConnection().prepareStatement(
     "FROM usuario");
   ResultSet res = pstm.executeQuery();
   res.next();
   registros = res.getInt("cont");
   res.close();
  }
 
  catch (SQLException e){
 System.out.println(e); 
}
  Object [][] data = new Object[registros][3];
  if (login.length() != 0 && password.length() != 0) {
   int usu_id;
   String usu_login = "";
   String usu_password = "";
   try {
    String strsql = "";
    strsql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = '" + login + "' AND password = '"+ password + "'";
      PreparedStatement pstm = cn.getConnection().prepareStatement(strsql);
      ResultSet res = pstm.executeQuery();
      int i = 0;
      while (res.next()){
       usu_id = res.getInt("idUsuario");
       usu_login = res.getString("login");
       usu_password = res.getString("password");
       data[i][0] = usu_id;
       data[i][1] = usu_login;
       data [i][2] = usu_password;
       i++;
      }
   res.close();
   }
   catch(SQLException e){
    System.out.println(e);
   }
   
  }
 return data;
 }
}
```

```js
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import DB.*;


public class InterfazLogin extends JFrame {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private JTextField txtusuario;
 private JPasswordField txtpassword;
 private JButton btnAceptar, btnCancelar;
 private JLabel lblusuario, lblpassword;
 private Container contenedor;
 private GridLayout cuadricula1;
 public InterfazLogin ()
  {
   super ("Acceso al programa");
   cuadricula1 = new GridLayout (3, 3, 10, 10);
   
   lblusuario = new JLabel("Usuario:");
   lblpassword = new JLabel ("Contraseña:");
   
   txtusuario = new  JTextField(10);
   txtpassword = new JPasswordField(10);
   
   btnAceptar = new JButton ("Aceptar");
   btnAceptar.setMnemonic('A');
   ImageIcon imgAceptar = new ImageIcon ("img/user_go.png");
   btnAceptar.setIcon(imgAceptar);
   
   btnCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");
   btnCancelar.setMnemonic('C');
   ImageIcon imgCancelar = new ImageIcon ("img/sign_cancel.gif");
   btnCancelar.setIcon(imgCancelar);
   
   contenedor = getContentPane();
   contenedor.setLayout(cuadricula1);
   contenedor.add(lblusuario);
   contenedor.add(txtusuario);
   contenedor.add(lblpassword);
   contenedor.add(txtpassword);
   contenedor.add(btnAceptar);
   contenedor.add(btnCancelar);
   
   btnAceptar.addActionListener(
     new ActionListener ()
     {
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento)
      {
       Usuario user = new Usuario ();
       PrincipalLogin principal = new PrincipalLogin ();
       String usuario;
       String password;
       
       usuario = txtusuario.getText();
       password = txtpassword.getText();
       
       try {
        Object [][] itemUsuario = user.UsuarioAcceder(usuario, password);
        String x_iduser = itemUsuario [0][0].toString();
        String x_user = itemUsuario [0][1].toString();
        String x_pass = itemUsuario[0][2].toString();
        if ((x_user !="")&& (x_pass != ""))
        {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(InterfazLogin.this, 
           "Bienvenido a Moogy usuario: " + x_user + ", con id: " + x_iduser,
           "Acerca de",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
          principal.mostrarForm(true);
          principal.setLocationRelativeTo(principal.getParent());
          dispose ();
        }
       }
       catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(InterfazLogin.this,
          "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto",
          "Acerca de", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       }
      }
     }
  );
   btnCancelar.addActionListener(
     new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evento)
      {
       System.exit(0);
       
      }
     }
     );
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setResizable(false);
   setSize(300,150);
   setVisible(true);
   setLocationRelativeTo(this.getParent());
  }
 
}
```

```js
import javax.swing.*;

public class Principal {
 public static void main ( String args [])
 {
  JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
  try {
   UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
  }
  catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println(e);
  }
  InterfazLogin aplicacion = new InterfazLogin ();
  aplicacion.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
 }
}
```

```js
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
public class PrincipalLogin extends JFrame {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private JMenuBar barramenu;
 public PrincipalLogin()
 {
  super("VENTANA DE ACCESO MOOGY");
 }
 
  public void mostrarForm (boolean mostrar){
   if (mostrar == true){
    barramenu = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menuArchivo = new JMenu ("Ajustes");
    menuArchivo.setMnemonic('C');
    
    JMenuItem itemAcerca = new JMenuItem("Acerca de....");
    itemAcerca.setMnemonic('A');
    menuArchivo.add(itemAcerca);
    itemAcerca.addActionListener(
      new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento)
       {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PrincipalLogin.this,
          "Acceso a Moogy", "Acerca de", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);  
      }
     }
   );
  JMenuItem itemSalir = new JMenuItem("Salir");
  itemSalir.setMnemonic('S');
  menuArchivo.add(itemSalir);
  itemSalir.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento)
     {
      System.exit(0);
      
     }
    }
    );
  barramenu.add(menuArchivo);
  setJMenuBar(barramenu);
  setSize(1022,700);
  setLocationRelativeTo(this.getParent());
  setVisible(mostrar);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
  
  }
}
```

Comment: Al parecer tu error esta aqui `PreparedStatement pstm = cn.getConnection().prepareStatement("FROM usuario");` te falta agregar la sentencia completa  `PreparedStatement pstm = cn.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM usuario");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes mucho código.
Tendrías que ir probando por partes.
Una clase te devuelve la conexión, intenta determinar si te la devuelve o tienen un nulo.
Luego te falla la query, hazla más sencilla: solo para probar que se procesa:

```
"SELECT * FROM usuario"
```

Si va bien, sera la sintaxis de tu sentencia, mira como la construyes, las comillas por ejemplo suelen dar problemas, trázala para ver si parece correcta antes de crear el PreparedStatement:

```
System.out.println( sentencia );
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione  gracias por su ayuda, lo que faltaba era agregar esto al PreparedStatement                                                     PreparedStatement pstm = cn.getConnection().prepareStatement(
     "SELECT count(1) as cont" +
   " FROM usuario");